# Change the look of an EditText prgrammatically

Tags: java, android, eclipse, styles

I'm making an app that works as follows:

when you click a button, there will appear an EditText and a Button and a TextView. 
I have already done that, but the style is not the same as the style when I create the EditText in xml (it looks different, the colour is not the same).

There will always be a couple of EditTexts, so the user will see the difference very well.
I also prefer the colour of the EditText when I create it in xml.
How can I change the style of an EditText programmatically?

Thanks in advance!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/24dzI.png (picture from the difference)

Comment: You get the same issue in all versions? Jelly bean, Kitkat, Lollipop...

Comment: No, I run the app on my own device, not on the emulator, it's to slow... But I'll give it a try!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that the background is being set differently between the two fields.  You can just use *setBackground(...)* to have it match the other fields.

If you need to get the proper background drawable, look up one of the existing fields, grab the background from there, and assign it to your dynamic field.

Comment: I used setBackgroundColor(..), to set the background color to white, but that didn't work, it didn't look the same as the one in xml... Also, I tried to set the background to transparent, but that didn't work too. Is there a difference between setBackground(..) and setBackgroundColor(..)?

Comment: Thanks you very much! This has solved my problem! editText.setBackground(word1.getBackground()); Now it looks the same as  the background from word1 (which I like!). Answer accepted!

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html

You can use EditText.setTypeFace() or EditText.setTextAppearance(), depending on what you're trying to change. The link has all the methods that EditText can perform.

Comment: No, I want to change the colour, in xml its kind of transparent/white, and in java code it's black and it looks different. Maybe style is not a good word to explain this...

Comment: Do you know how I can do this?

Comment: You mean set the color of the text?  EditText.setTextColor(int color)

Comment: If not, what specifically do you want to change the color of?

Comment: I want to change the background, to the same color of the background from the edittext in xml. I tried to do that, but it didn't look the same... Also when I set the background to white, it wasn't exactly the same colour of the edittext in xml.